# R Shiny - Display Table Based on Input Parameter

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

For the life of me I can't work this out, I'm using Flexdashboard in R Studio and I have two tables. What I want to be able to do is to switch the table being being shown via a selectInput. My selectInput is currently:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(png)
library(grid)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
selectInput("platform", label = "Select Platform:",
              choices = c("MB","DS"))
```
````

The csv files for MB_Val and DS_Val can be extracted from here:

DS_Val [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2nt7st14jyhdzs3/DS_Val.csv?dl=0)

MB_Val [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1i306ywu5xugsr/MB_Val.csv?dl=0)

My two charts are as follows:

```
MB_Val %>%
  mutate(Val = cell_spec(
    format(round(Val, 2), nsmall = 2), "html", color = "white", bold = T,
    background = "#7FC64F")) %>% 
  mutate(ValFm = cell_spec(
    format(round(ValFm, 2), nsmall = 2), "html", color = "white", bold = T,
    background = "#7FC64F")) %>% 
  kable("html", escape = F, align = c('l',rep('c',ncol(MB_Val)-1))) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "condensed","hover")) %>%
  scroll_box()
```

and

```
DS_Val %>%
  mutate(Val = cell_spec(
    format(round(Val, 2), nsmall = 2), "html", color = "white", bold = T,
    background = "#7FC64F")) %>%
  mutate(ValFm = cell_spec(
    format(round(ValFm, 2), nsmall = 2), "html", color = "white", bold = T,
    background = "#7FC64F")) %>%
 kable("html", escape = F,align = c('l',rep('c',ncol(DS_Val)-1))) %>%
 kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "condensed","hover")) %>%
 scroll_box(height = "200px")
```

I've tried a number of things, the most recent being this. I'd love to be able to keep all the formatting too if possible.

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
div(renderTable({ifelse(input$platform %in% c("MB"),MB_Val,DS_Val)}),
 style = "font-size:80%")
```
````

Comment: please provide a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Have added links to csv files to allow re-production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you print the contents of your `kable_extra` objects, you can see that their output is HTML:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px; overflow-y: scroll; height:200px; "><table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="text-align:left;"> Player.Name </th>
   <th style="text-align:center;"> Tm </th>
   <th style="text-align:center;"> Pos </th>
   <th style="text-align:center;"> Sal </th>
   <th style="text-align:center;"> Gms </th>
...
...
```

So instead of `renderTable` you should use `renderUI`:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
renderUI( {
  data <- ifelse(input$platform %in% c("MB"), MB_table, DS_table)
  HTML(data)
})
```
````

I assigned the output objects to `MD_table` and `DS_table` in the setup chunk, since you haven't included an assignment in your example:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(png)
library(grid)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
library(shiny)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

DS_Val <- read_csv("DS_Val.csv")
MB_Val <- read_csv("MB_Val.csv")


MB_table <- MB_Val %>%
  mutate(Val = cell_spec(
    format(round(Val, 2), nsmall = 2), "html", color = "white", bold = T,
    background = "#7FC64F")) %>% 
  mutate(ValFm = cell_spec(
    format(round(ValFm, 2), nsmall = 2), "html", color = "white", bold = T,
    background = "#7FC64F")) %>% 
  kable("html", escape = F, align = c('l',rep('c',ncol(MB_Val)-1))) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "condensed","hover")) %>%
  scroll_box()

DS_table <- DS_Val %>%
  mutate(Val = cell_spec(
    format(round(Val, 2), nsmall = 2), "html", color = "white", bold = T,
    background = "#7FC64F")) %>%
  mutate(ValFm = cell_spec(
    format(round(ValFm, 2), nsmall = 2), "html", color = "white", bold = T,
    background = "#7FC64F")) %>%
 kable("html", escape = F,align = c('l',rep('c',ncol(DS_Val)-1))) %>%
 kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "condensed","hover")) %>%
 scroll_box(height = "200px")
```
````

Result:

[image]